# How do I make my JavaScript code reflect on the live server in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I am creating a website using VS Code. I haev completed the HTML and CSS part. I started writing JS but whatever I write in JS does not reflect in the live server. Is there any extension or any setting that I need to change?

I tried installing some extensions like preview.JS but nothing worked.

Comment: Does it not automatically refresh the page when you save the javascript file? How does the javascript file you are referring to get used in the index.html page? Does it get used in the index.html page at all? Can you provide steps and code to reproduce the issue? ([mre])

Comment: How is your script being included? Is it being cached?

Comment: You have to refresh the page after saving the file

Comment: I have linked my javascript file to the html file. I even tried refreshing the page but nothing changes.